# Split double-digit NSInteger into Two NSIntegers

Tags: ios, nsinteger

I am trying to figure out how to take a double-digit NSInteger on iOS (like 11) and turn it into 2 separate NSIntegers, each looking like "1".  It will always be just 2 digits in the NSInteger, no more, no less, and no decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use integer/modulo arithmetic

```
int tensDigit=originalNumber / 10;
int onesDigit=originalNumber % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger a=11;
NSInteger b=a%10;
NSInteger c=(a-b)/10;
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",a,b,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this it work  (In Swift).

```
var number  = 36

var tenPlace = number / 10

var UnitPlace = number % 10
```

see the Screen shot.

[image]

Comment: You should put your actual code into your answer as it can be copied easily while a screenshot cannot

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide by 10 and find the reminder of division by 10.

```
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:21];
NSNumber* partOne = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([number integerValue] / 10)];
NSNumber* partTwo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([number integerValue] % 10)];
```

for 21, **partOne** will be 2 and **partTwo** will be 1.

In general, for any number *n*, *i*th digit is n % pow(10, i)